# Not Found when shortening URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

So I have shortened `article.php?id=10` to `article/10`. And it all seemed to work fine. But little did I know that it ruined the rest of my URLs. So with `http://localhost/forgot/`, I'd have to go to `http://localhost/forgot/index` to actually reach it. Here's what I'm using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I want  to go to `http://localhost/forgot/` instead of `http://localhost/forgot/index`/ Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# rewrite from /dir/file/ to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```